# sphinx MVA with rt_attr_string

Tags: sphinx

I am not sure about question title. But i have tried it very hard.

My rt_index conf:

```
type            = rt
path            = C:\nginx\www\public_html\sphinx\scripts\data\rt_index
rt_field        = title
rt_field        = property
rt_attr_string  = title
rt_attr_string  = brand_name
rt_attr_string  = property
rt_attr_multi   = categories
rt_attr_uint    = price
rt_attr_uint    = brand_id
```

I am following : https://github.com/adriannuta/SphinxFacetingExample

Here am getting unique categories and number of product related to this category.
But it only return the category id as it is "rt_attr_multi".
My query is here how I can i get the names of categories with the id ?
I have created another index of categories :

```
index facetcats
{
type            = rt
path            = C:\nginx\www\public_html\sphinx\scripts\data\facetcats
rt_field        = cat_name
rt_attr_string  = cat_name    
}
```

But not able to join two index.

My goal is getting the category names without query to DB.

plz help me.

Answer (score 1):

Sphinx doesn't have a string MVA. (and there is no 'joins' in sphinx)

Frankly your best idea is to just use the database to lookup the names. They will be simple PK lookups so ridiculously fast - can even cache lookups with memcache or similar.

Or you can just use a plain string attribute, store it as say comma seperated (some seperator dont use in names)

The main gotcha is sphinx will reorder MVAs into numeric order (internally), so you should presort your category names into id numeric order before storing into attribute. (so can still match up category names to ids in the attributes)